# Result from the syntax: mysqldump

Tags: mysql

What will happen if I just write the syntax:

```
  mysqldump -u [username] -p [databse name]
```

I have tried searching for it but I only got results for the syntax:

```
  mysqldump -u [username] -p [databse name] > [backup file name].sql
```

Comment: You try it, then you know what will happen.

Comment: I tried it but I want to know where the files are saved.

Comment: Nothing will save, just show every thing on console. That is why your google result will tell you append "> backup_file_name.sql". Which redirect output into file backup_file_name.sql

Answer (score 0):

you can always try the command and see what it produces, it will prompt you for the password

> $ mysqldump -u root -p test
>
> Enter password:

Comment: Actually, I tried the command through Putty.exe and then it started displaying large number of lines quickly and all I managed to read was "dump table ....." So, I panicked and quickly closed the window and restored a backup from 2 days before. Now, I think the dump command saves a copy of the database somewhere but how do I retrieve it.